OpenAI API using C# - I want to ask the questions from the uploaded pdf file, but the prompt is giving some random answers
I am new in the world of using OpenAI API. I am using c# web api application to run my project. I have uploaded the pdf file and response is coming as successful. When i am trying to fetch the answer from the uploaded file using OpenAI api , some random response is getting generated. Kindly help me out on this.
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("UploadPDF")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadPDF(IFormFile pdfFile)
    {
        if (pdfFile != null && pdfFile.Length > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                // Save the uploaded file temporarily
                var tempFilePath = Path.GetTempFileName();
                using (var stream = new FileStream(tempFilePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await pdfFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
                }

                // Extract text from the PDF
                extractedText = ExtractTextFromPdf(tempFilePath);

                //// Delete the temporary file
                //System.IO.File.Delete(tempFilePath);

                return Ok(new { Message = "File processed successfully", ExtractedText = extractedText });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, new { Message = "ERROR: " + ex.Message });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest(new { Message = "You have not specified a file." });
        }
    }
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("AskQuestionPDF")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AskQuestionPDF([FromBody] string question)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(extractedText))
        {
            return BadRequest(new { Message = "No PDF content available. Please upload a PDF first." });
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(question))
        {
            return BadRequest(new { Message = "Question cannot be empty." });
        }

        try
        {
            var openai = new OpenAIAPI("API_KEY");
            var prompt = $"Based on the following text from the PDF, answer the      question.\n\nPDF Text:\n{extractedText}\n\nQuestion: {question}\nAnswer:";
            CompletionRequest completionRequest = new CompletionRequest
            {
                Prompt = prompt,
                Model = OpenAI_API.Models.Model.Davinci,
                MaxTokens = 150,
                Temperature = 0.1,
                TopP = 1.0
            };

            var completions = await openai.Completions.CreateCompletionAsync(completionRequest);
            string answer = "";
            foreach (var i in completions.Completions)
            {
                answer += i.Text;
            }

            return Ok(new { Question = question, Answer = answer });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(500, new { Message = "ERROR: " + ex.Message });
        }
    }


Showing the UploadPDF method seems irrelevant. AskQuestionPDF gets texts that is send to the AI. If you have checked that the question as plaintext is given correctly to the AskQuestionPDF remove UploadPDF(and ExtractTextFromPdf) from your question to reduce clutter and make it easier to concentrate on relevant code and therefore easier to help.

Oh. Have you checked that "extractedText" variable actually has content? We don't see where its coming from. Be aware that any endpoint call will create a new Controller instance. If you set "extractedText " in one endpoint the other endpoint will not see it as its a different Controller instance.

Hi @Ralf initially i have assigned the value of extractedtext as string.empty. When the file is uploaded extractedtext gets some data as "BDCgsgmlllllllllhfEMC BDCqreWnBTTfTmggsGTJETQqreW*nBTTfTmgGTJETQEMC ... .

That is presumably not the plain text content of the PDF. At least it looks to me not like something being answerable by an AI or any other entity.

You need to make clear what the difference is between "extractedText" and "question" in the AskQuestionPDF method.

extractedtext are the text which is getting extract from the pdf and AskQuestionPDF is the method where user can ask the questions related to the pdf
